# xclip Outputs "Error: Can't open display: (null)"

Tags: centos, x11, xclip

I recently installed `xclip` on my CentOS 7 server. Since my machine does not have an X server, I'd have to configure my machine to forward X11 to my client.

Following the steps explained in this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305654/xclip-on-headless-server/305681#305681):

- on my client(macOS 10.13), I wrote `ForwardX11 yes' in`~/.ssh/config`
- on my server(CentOS 7), I set `X11Forwarding` as `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

but I still can't get `xclip` to function on my server. I'm still getting the following error when I try to use `xclip`:

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
```

Also the command `echo $DISPLAY` outputs as empty.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Please explain (without assuming we can look over your shoulder): (1) what machines are involved, (2) how did you "forward X11 to [your] client", (3) what machine you're running `xclip` on.  Please edit your question instead of answering comments.

Comment: @SatōKatsura please see the edit

Comment: You need to restart `sshd` after changing `sshd_config`.

Comment: I did `sudo systemctl reload sshd` but it's all the same.

Comment: `ssh` sets `DISPLAY` if X11 forwarding works. Try `ssh -vv -X servername`, and look for something like `X11 forwarding request accepted`, or other messages giving hints why it doesn't forward.

Comment: @dirkt Outputs: `debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set`. Tried the suggested solution here http://bit.ly/2iqB2sK and various others on the internet with no luck.

Comment: So the X11 server on your client is running, or is it using Wayland? What's the output of `echo $DISPLAY` on your client (without `ssh`)?

Comment: @dirkt `echo $DISPLAY` on my client(macOS 10.13) is again an empty line. Since I'm on macOS, I believe I'm not using Wayland.

Comment: Not familiar with macOS, but if you are not running some kind of X server on the macOS client, then of course `ssh` can't forward an X connection. See if macOS provides some means to simulate or run an X server.